# LogWriter: Operating system error 1117

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption

I am getting these errors on my dedicated server because of which database goes into recovery mode.

I have seen the following error in SQL server error log file:

```
2018-01-20 05:32:19.83 spid7s      LogWriter: Operating system error 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.) encountered.
2018-01-20 05:32:19.83 spid7s      Write error during log flush.
2018-01-20 05:32:19.84 spid284     The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 284, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2018-01-20 05:32:19.84 spid335     Database newtrack was shutdown due to error 9001 in routine 'XdesRMFull::Commit'. Restart for non-snapshot databases will be attempted after all connections to the database are aborted.
2018-01-20 05:35:03.35 spid22s     Recovery completed for database aa(database ID 7) in 151 second(s) (analysis 18856 ms, redo 115386 ms, undo 2023 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

At the same time following errors are generated in event viewer:

```
Application Event
EventID:17053, MSSQLSERVER
LogWriter: Operating system error 1117
    (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.) encountered.
Error 1/20/2018 5:32:19 AM MSSQLSERVER 18056 Server
Error 1/20/2018 5:32:19 AM MSSQLSERVER 9001 Server
Error 1/20/2018 5:32:19 AM MSSQLSERVER 9001 Server
Error 1/20/2018 5:32:19 AM MSSQLSERVER 17053 Server

System Event:
The IO operation at logical block address 4069 for Disk 1
    (PDO name: \Device\00000045) was retried.
```

Comment: I recommend you read [this](http://erinstellato.com/2011/04/some-errors-not-they-seem/) article by Erin Stellato.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that you are running in a VMWare environment [and configured Paravirtual SCSI) adapters. See [this knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2519834/sql-server-reports-operating-system-error-1117-i-o-device-error-on-vmw)

> SQL Server reports "Operating system error 1117 (I/O Device Error)" on
>   VMware ESX environments that are configured to use PVSCSI adapters

Unfortunately the link to the VMWare knowledgebase in that article is dead but there is an official VMWare KB [article here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004578). If this describes your situation you might want to open a support call with VMWare.